# Calling functions from IDAPython

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

I wrote a script containing several functions, which I loaded in IDA pro. From IDAPython now I'd want to call a specific function. Is it possible? Which idaapi functions should I use to call my functions in the script?

EDIT:
I am running IDA on a linux system and the script has been written in python.

Comment: how did you load these functions to IDA pro ? Is the script is wrote in  IDAPython too ?

Comment: Just updated the post. I uploaded the script using the IDA functionality

Comment: Would you please explain which IDA functionality did you use ? And how are you going to run your script ?

Comment: What do you mean? I just load the script using File->Load file->Script file. Or by using (from shell) ida -Smyscript mybin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 alternatives:

1. You can just run the function by its name. If you already ran your script, defined functions should remain in the Python interpreter context.
2. You can add the path of your script to sys.path and import the script again. It should looks as follows:

   ```
   import sys

   sys.path.append("path to your folder with the script")

   import your_script_name
   ```
3. You can add this (addition to sys.path and import) into file `idapythonrc.py` in the root of IDA installation and this script will be imported each time you running IDA.